Error loading Noto Sans Imperial Aramaic: does not contain Imperial Aramaic
I am trying to load the Imperial Aramaic font (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/notofonts/notofonts.github.io/fonts/NotoSansImperialAramaic/unhinted/otf/NotoSansImperialAramaic-Regular.otf) into my fonts directory within a project. When I do the following:
\newfontfamily\aramaicfont[Script=Imperial Aramaic,
        Path=fonts/,
        UprightFont=*-Regular,
        Extension=.otf]{Noto Sans Imperial Aramaic}

I receive the following warning:
Package fontspec Warning: Font "NotoSansImperialAramaic-Regular" does not
(fontspec)                contain requested Script "Imperial Aramaic".

Looking through the font, it appears that it does indeed provide the "armi" script and correctly references the ISO name. Is this a problem with the font, an issue with fontspec, or user error from something I'm missing?
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023/Cygwin)
Development id: 7567
$ cat mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newfontfamily\aramaicfont[Script=Imperial Aramaic,
        Path=fonts/,
        UprightFont=*-Regular,
        Extension=.otf]{Noto Sans Imperial Aramaic}

\newcommand{\textaramaic}[1]{\bgroup\textdir TRT\aramaicfont #1\egroup}

\begin{document}
Test: \textaramaic{}
\end{document}


otfinfo --scripts NotoSansImperialAramaic-Regular.otf  does not show any script and otfinfo --features NotoSansImperialAramaic-Regular.otf also does not show any feature.

Thanks @cabohah! I went ahead and reported it upstream: https://github.com/notofonts/imperial-aramaic/issues/2

Not sure what’s happening, but since you are loading babel you can consider using the minimal support currently available for Aramaic (a very recent version is required). Here is a couple of examples:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=default, english]{babel}

\babelfont[aramaic]{rm}
% [Path=fonts/, UprightFont=*-Regular, Extension=.otf]
  {Noto Sans Imperial Aramaic}

\begin{document}
One \foreignlanguage{aramaic}{} Two.
\end{document}

If you want to switch the font and the direction with the script:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, english]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{aramaic}

\babelfont[aramaic]{rm}
% [Path=fonts/, UprightFont=*-Regular, Extension=.otf]
  {Noto Sans Imperial Aramaic}

\begin{document}
One  Two.
\end{document}

The result in both cases is


Congrats on surpassing the 10k reputation mark on this site!

@Mico Thank you!
